# How can i stop node installing on every opening? Glitch.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, glitch-framework

```
Initializing node_modules, hold on...
node v12.0.0, with pnpm
Installing...
Performing headless installation
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Packages: +85
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Resolving: total 85, reused 84, downloaded 1
Resolving: total 85, reused 84, downloaded 1, done
dependencies:
+ discord.js 11.4.2
+ dotenv 8.2.0
+ express 4.17.1
+ rgb-hex 3.0.0
+ util 0.12.3
Total install time: 3722ms
```

My app's node is always installing again himself in every opening. And my app would closed a few minutes later. How can i stop this installing in every opening?

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Sure.[Click here](http://4gp.me/busd/1600460167350.htm)

Comment: This code's start is worse. In real code, everything is great for syntax.

Comment: I sent code with text format. Because i can't send here all of the package.json.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

To stop auto-installing and restarting every time you change something in a file, you've got to create a file named as **watch.json**.

### Examples

First of all create the **watch.json** at root level. Throttle time specifies the time to wait after a change began

#### Disable auto-restart on your whole project

```
{
  "install": {
    "include": [
      "^.trigger-rebuild$"
    ]
  },
  "throttle": 100
}
```

#### Disable auto-restart on public directory and restart on changes with .js files

```
{
  "install": {
    "include": [
      "^\\.env$"
    ]
  },
  "restart": {
    "exclude": [
      "^public/"
    ],
    "include": [
      "\\.js$"
    ]
  },
  "throttle": 100
}
```

### Reference

[watch.json example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/watch-json)

Comment: Use [this Glitch.com project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/acoustic-tin-sherbet) as example.

Comment: Can you please describe more in detail how is your directory tree/hierarchy and what is your expected output? As I mentioned by creating the **watch.json** you'll be able to handle the events on **specific** files/directories as long as you define it in the **watch.json**.

Comment: My directory tree: public(folder) views(folder) .env README.md package.json server.js watch.json

Comment: My excepted output is only a printout that the program is running. This is printed after the downloads I mentioned. And I complain that these downloads are made at every boot and the program crashes about 15-30 minutes later.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour, can you please share your project by clicking on **share > Project Page** and then copy the link ***Link to Glitch*** (don't copy the URL which allows us to edit your project) in order to "remix" your project and see what happens in there.

Comment: I can see the problem was here `"^package\\.json$"` this line has to be deleted. My apologies, let me edit my answer. I don't want to edit your project without permission, just delete the line I mentioned and you will see the changes. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this communication. I will check how long the robot will last. If there is a problem, I write it as a comment.

Comment: It was able to stand for exactly 23 minutes. It could not stand up again.

Comment: NOTE: My bot is uptiming with [UptimeRobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) and [StatusCake](https://statuscake.com).

Comment: I guess they blocked the external standing system.